# Compute modulo 2^32 - 1 operation without division

Tags: algorithm, random, cryptography, modulo, number-theory

I was reading about [CMWC PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry_pseudorandom_number_generator#Complementary-multiply-with-carry_generators) and found the claim that it is possible to compute `a mod (2^32 - 1)` without using slow modulo operation. My question is very similar to [Is there any easy way to do modulus of 2^32 - 1 operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857080/is-there-any-easy-way-to-do-modulus-of-232-1-operation) but I found only while-loop-based solutions for the general case of large `a` that may be even larger than `2^64`.

I tried to understand how the authors of CMWC [implemented their algorithm (page 9)](https://doi.org/10.22237%2Fjmasm%2F1051747320) without loops and extracted crucial piece of it. I wrote it in python pseudocode to make it more clear when modulo division by 2^32 happens as C++ implementation hides it behind unsigned overflow. So the following fragment of code

```
c = (a // b) % b
x = (a + c) % b
if (x < c):
    x = (x + 1)
    c = (c + 1)
```

is equivalent to

```
x = a % (b - 1)
c = a // (b - 1)
```

It works for `b = 2^32` and `0 <= a < 2^64` when `a % (2^32 - 1) != 0` (such `a` seems to be never used in this PRNG).
Actually, this pseudocode works correctly even in the general case of `b > 3`, `0 <= a < b^2`, `a % (b - 1) != 0`.

So my question is how to explain that the pseudocode above works at all? I don't understand the reasoning behind it and wondering how I could come up with this simplification of division myself.

Comment: Somebody just recognized a pattern that works up to `b^2 - 1`, but doesn't work when `a % (b-1) == 0`. To see the pattern for yourself, choose a smallish `b` like `b=8`. Then for each `a` from 0 to 63, print `a`, `a%7`, `a//7`. If `a%7` is not 0, print the raw `x` and `c` values from the first snippet, and the adjusted `x` and `c` values if `x < c`. Then ponder the results before you on the screen, and you'll understand it as well as anybody does.

Comment: if u need "to explain that the pseudocode" to ur self.. this should do.. but if u need a proving method (like writing a paper..) then here might not be the best place.. I think [math.se] SE suits this question better.